# Referencing a .css file in github repo as stylesheet in a .html file

Tags: github

I've got a repository on github with a .css file in it. Is there any way to have github serve this file in a way that I can consume it in a web page?

In other words, I'd like to be able to reference this source file at github directly, from an HTML file on my local computer or a live domain. Something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="http://github.com/foouser/barproject/master/xenu-is-my-lover.css"
/>
```

I've tried including a`<link>` to the "raw" source file (`http://raw.github.com...`), but github serves its `Content-Type` as `text/plain`, and consequently, Chrome and FF are not adding its content as CSS styles to the page—the file's data is being discarded and a warning is shown in the debugger consoles of the browsers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Link and execute external JavaScript file hosted on GitHub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341122/link-and-execute-external-javascript-file-hosted-on-github)

Comment: (try this) You can create a `folder/file.css` and serve it from GitHub pages. Just follow the correct path from the URL and get the file when referencing it from your local html file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

GitHub repos aren't web hosting, you should push that stuff up to a service specifically designed to serve files, like pages.github.com.

Comment: I don't think this is true. You can host static files on github, granted web hosting is better but it can work on github pages.

Answer (score 66):

**Important**: rawgit.com is shutting down. Read more about other alternatives here - https://rawgit.com/

---

Found something really cool. You get the raw link as: `http://raw.github.com/...`

Simply fetch the files from [rawgit.com](https://rawgit.com/) (or `cdn.rawgit.com`) instead of `raw.github.com` and DONE!

**UPDATE:**

You can also use [raw.githack.com](https://raw.githack.com/) if you want to serves raw files directly from **Bitbucket** or **GitLab**

Comment: Just what I needed to serve the proper MIME type!

Comment: Keep in mind that you should not use [rawgithub](http://rawgithub.com/) for production code.

Comment: Mind Blown. Private gists and repo's don't work. just as an FYI

Comment: JsDelivr does this apparently! Example: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/StylishThemes/Syntax-Themes/pygments/css-github/pygments-tomorrow-night-eighties.css from [this GitHub file](https://github.com/StylishThemes/Syntax-Themes/blob/master/pygments/css-github/pygments-tomorrow-night-eighties.css). This service seems to have been around for a long time, and widely used.

Answer (score 9):

Check out https://gitcdn.link/ .  Seems to work well.

Rawgit.com has shut down.

Comment: Does not like this works either; there is a front page, but About etc do not resolve ("Cannot GET /about"), and when you try to paste a link, you get nothing in the text field?

Comment: This seems to be abandoned too unfortunately. Might be due to Heroku removing its free tier and removing inactive accounts.

Answer (score 2):

- First Visit [RawGit](https://rawgit.com/) as suggested earlier
- Next copy your file path from github into the RawGit box
- RawGit will automatically produce two refrences to your web page
- The Development and Production refrence
- refrence the development link in your webpage if you are still developing
- save/upload then reload your webpage
- if there was no change it means your browser has saved your former refrence
- clear your browser data then reload