# Chrome userscript is not applying remote CSS stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, github, userscripts

Direct link to script: https://github.com/MosheBerman/MinimalOverflow/blob/master/styleswitcher.user.js

I downloaded a script from https://stackapps.com/questions/2143/minimaloverflow-a-themescript-for-stack-exchange and drag and dropped the *.user.js file into my extensions tab in Chrome. The script runs, which I verified by using an `alert`. I even `alert`ed the `href` attribute in the script to verify that it was changing it properly.

However whenever the script changes the CSS, there is no styling applied:
[image: no styling applied]

Essentially the code looks for the `link` tag and changes the `href` attribute.

**line 64**

```
function switchToStylesheet(sheet){

    for(var i=0; i<linkElements.length; i++){   
        if(linkElements[i].getAttribute("rel") == "stylesheet"){

            //apply the new stylesheet
            linkElements[i].href = sheet;

            alert(linksElements[i].href); 
// shows https://github.com/MosheBerman/MinimalOverflow/raw/master/clean.css as expected

            //We only want to replace the first stylesheet, so return.
            //If SO decides to change any styles, just put it in a 
            //second stylesheet and link tag. The script should safely ignore it.
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I have `Version 25.0.1364.152`
And I'm running `Windows 7 64-bit`

Can anyone verify if this is a `Chrome`, `Javascript`, or `Userscript` issue?

Comment: This is not what you want, but as an alternative method you might want to try: Stylish  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe ( The plugin is also available for _other browsers_ ). The search for stackoverfllow styles ( http://userstyles.org/styles/browse/stackoverflow ) didn't seem to come up with similar styles, but it's fairly easy to just inspect elements in a website and overwrite them with your own css with Stylish...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See ["Referencing a .css file in github repo as stylesheet in a .html file"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7780550/331508).  Git serves up the CSS file (`.../raw/master/clean.css`) with the wrong mime type; so browsers like Chrome and Firefox will not (normally) process/apply such CSS.

The quick fix is to host that CSS file on your own server, or one of the free file hosting sites.  Then change the script setting to:

```
var pathToNewStylesheet = "http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/clean.css";
```

Comment: Thanks..can't believe how many hoops I had to jump through..There's no such thing as 'accessibility' anymore.