# How to add css to my page via Git Hub raw?

Tags: html, css, github, frameworks, repository

I have a css file on my git hub. I get a link to raw file ([example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Koi7/github-linker/master/fork-me.css)) 
When I add it by link I see styles not applied to my elements. Viewing source code in Firefox I see a working link to my style.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Koi7/github-linker/master/fork-me.css">
```

Comment: Hard to say - if you did not write a link to page where you want to use those styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780550/referencing-a-css-file-in-github-repo-as-stylesheet-in-a-html-file)

be sure you are using the right url based on whether this is a development project or a production website.

see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/colost8rams/dn1bgd6x/1/) for an example.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/Koi7/github-linker/master/fork-me.css">

<a class="fork-me-link" href="#"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Koi7/github-linker/master/git-hub-link.png" alt=""></a>
```