# Stylesheet not loading from a URL (GitHub raw)

Tags: html, css, git, bootstrap-4, glyphicons

How are you doing?

First, thank you for trying to help, I know this question is silly but I couldn't find an answer nor understand why it is not working as expected.

I have the following *tree* on my machine:

```
projectFolder
  |__ website
        |__index.html
```

For this website, I'm using Bootstrap 4, but I needed to use *glyphicons* from Bootstrap 3, so I saved the *glyphicons* part from Bootstrap 3 in a `.css` file called `glyphicons.css`. I then uploaded this file to GitHub, which raw version is available [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/feRpicoral/GlyphiconsBootstrap4/master/glyphicons.css).

When I tried using it in `index.html`, using the following line to import it, it didn't work.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/feRpicoral/GlyphiconsBootstrap4/master/glyphicons.css" type="text/css">
```

Nevertheless, when I download the file and added it to `projectFolder`, resulting in the following path, it worked fine, so the problem is not in the `.css` file.

```
projectFolder/glyphicons.css
```

To import the file I was using the same `<link>` as above but with `"../glyphicons.css"` as `href`.

**Long story short, when importing a stylesheet hosted on GitHub using the *raw* link of the file, it does not work.**

Am I doing something wrong?

Below you can see the relevant part of the `glyphicon.css` file and the code that I'm using in `index.html`. Feel free to run the snippet and understand better what I mean.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

    src: url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
    src: url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
.glyphicon {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.glyphicon-picture:before {
    content: "\e060";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <!-- Bootstrap4 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Glyphicons File -->
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="../glyphicons.css" type="text/css"> WORKS (COMMENTED TO USE WITH STACKOVERFLOW SNIPPET)-->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/feRpicoral/GlyphiconsBootstrap4/master/glyphicons.css" type="text/css"> DOESN'T WORK-->


  <title>Glyphicons Test</title>
</head>

<body>

  <style type="text/css">
    div {
      font-size: 100px;
      margin: 100px auto;
    }
    
    #text {
      font-size: 20px;
      display: block;
    }
  </style>


  <div class="container bg-dark text-center text-white">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span>
    <span id="text">Icon is above if working</span>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance,
Fernando

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55054746/8757883) - and [gitcdn](https://gitcdn.link/) you can create a link which you can refer to in your HTML... i removed the css code where you had loaded the glyphicons and now all glyphicons are loaded from your git link;

```css
div {
  font-size: 100px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

#text {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <!-- Bootstrap4 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://gitcdn.link/repo/feRpicoral/GlyphiconsBootstrap4/master/glyphicons.css" />

  <title>Glyphicons Test</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container bg-dark text-center text-white">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span>
    <span id="text">Icon is above if working</span>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```